# Trouble checking if the returnType is HttpNotFoundResult using xunit testing mvc.controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, testing, xunit

I am trying to test a `Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Controller` that return `Task<IActionResult>` if the id passed in gets a hit, and returns a `HttpNotFound()` if no hits.

How can I, using xUnit, test to see if what i get back is the HttpNotFound or an actual result?

This is Controller method:

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Get(string id)
{
    var company = await _repository.GetSingle(id);
    if (company == null)
        return HttpNotFound();

    return new ObjectResult(company);
}
```

And this is the test method (that is not working):

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("1")]
[InlineData("01")]
[InlineData("10")]
public async void TestGetSingleNonExistingCompany(string id)
{
    var controller = new CompanyController(new CompanyRepositoryMock());
    try
    {
        var res = await controller.Get(id);
        Assert.False(true);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Assert.True(true);
    }
}
```

The problem I guess is that the `controller.Get(id)` does not actually throw an `Exception`, but I cannot use `typeOf`, because the type of the `res` variable is decided at compile-time, and not runtime.

When running the Assert.IsType :

```
[Theory]
[InlineData("1")]
[InlineData("01")]
[InlineData("10")]
public async void TestGetSingleNonExistingCompany(string id)
{
    var controller = new CompanyController(new CompanyRepositoryMock());
    var res = await controller.Get(id);
    Assert.IsType(typeof (HttpNotFoundResult), res.GetType());
}
```

I get this message:

```
Assert.IsType() Failure
Expected: Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.HttpNotFoundResult
Actual:   System.RuntimeType
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter for [`Assert.IsType`](http://www.nudoq.org/#!/Packages/xunit.extensions/xunit.extensions/Assertions/M/IsType) should be the object itself that you're checking the type of and not the type of the object. Try this, and your assert should succeed when the result of `HttpNotFound()` is returned:

```
Assert.IsType(typeof (HttpNotFoundResult), res);
```